# How to get the Filled data from the pdf viewer using pdfjs library

Tags: javascript, html, pdf.js

I am using pdfjs library for my pdf file, in which users have to fill the details on pdf viewer and then I am trying to get the filled pdf from iframe, but I am getting the Cross origin error like this.
`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Permission denied to access property "fetch" on cross-origin object`

Here is the code which I am using for my example

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib@1.17.1/dist/pdf-lib.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/downloadjs@1.4.7"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick="fillForm()">Fill PDF</button>
    <button onclick="getNewPDF()">Get Updated PDF</button>
    <iframe id="frPDF" 
    sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"
    src="pdfFile"
    style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" type="application/pdf"></iframe>
  </body>

  <script>
    const { PDFDocument } = PDFLib

    async function fillForm() {
        // Fetch the PDF with form fields
      const formUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/pdfFile.pdf'
      const formPdfBytes = await fetch(formUrl, {method: 'get', mode: 'cors', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'}
      }).then(res => res.arrayBuffer())

            // Fetch the Mario image
      const marioUrl = 'https://pdf-lib.js.org/assets/small_mario.png'
      const marioImageBytes = await fetch(marioUrl).then(res => res.arrayBuffer())

            // Fetch the emblem image
      const emblemUrl = 'https://pdf-lib.js.org/assets/mario_emblem.png'
      const emblemImageBytes = await fetch(emblemUrl).then(res => res.arrayBuffer())

      // Load a PDF with form fields
      const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(formPdfBytes)

      // Embed the Mario and emblem images
      const marioImage = await pdfDoc.embedPng(marioImageBytes)
      const emblemImage = await pdfDoc.embedPng(emblemImageBytes)

      const form = pdfDoc.getForm()

      const nameField = form.getTextField('name')
      nameField.setText('Shoaib Raza')

      const addressField = form.getTextField('address')
      addressField.setText('Hello World')

      const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.saveAsBase64()
      document.getElementById("frPDF").src = "data:application/pdf;base64,"+(pdfBytes);
    }
  
    async function getNewPDF(){
      const iframe = document.getElementById("frPDF");
      const contentWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
      const pdfData = await contentWindow.fetch(iframe.src).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());

      // Load PDF document from the iframe
      const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfData);

      // Generate new PDF document with updated values
      const pdfBase64 = await pdfDoc.saveAsBase64();
      console.log(pdfBase64);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

I am getting error on `getNewPDF` function.

Anyone can help me out this, that how can I get the filled data from pdf viewer.

Comment: @KJ Thank you for your response. `iframe.contentWindow` is actually is returning the undefined value that's why I am not able to get the pdf data . And also I fully understand the client and remote logic, that's why I have added the full example code in my question which is in JavaScript. As you mention in comment that after pdf viewer loaded than its belong to the client, yes you are right that it is on client side that's why I am using the JavaScript for getting the data because JavaScript is meant to be run on client side not the server side.

Comment: My challenge is that, the PDF is loaded on the iframe viewer which is on the client browser and JavaScript can manipulate the iframe but in my case I am getting the Cross Origin error while getting the data from iframe.